# Where is sdl-config installed on MacOS 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, sdl

After installing [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.14.dmg) and [SDL-devel](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-devel-1.2.14-extras.dmg) in MacOS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), trying to configure some source code that requires SDL yields:

```
checking for sdl-config... no
checking for SDL - version >= 1.2.0... no
*** The sdl-config script installed by SDL could not be found
*** If SDL was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the SDL_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to sdl-config.
configure: error: *** SDL version 1.2.0 not found!
```

Does anyone know where to find sdl-config? I guess I can build SDL from source, but why should I have to, when there exist pre-built packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

I found out that sdl-config was installed in two locations:

- /sw/bin/sdl-config

and

- /opt/local/bin/sdl-config

In the one located in /sw/bin I changed the prefix to /opt/local — then it worked.

Answer (score 15):

you can use macports to install libsdl or  libsdl-devel (v1.2 or v1.3)

http://www.macports.org/

after installing macports to install libsdl type
`port install libsdl`

it will install sdl-config at /opt/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

The output you're showing is from a unix style configure for automake. According to this site: http://www.libsdl.org/faq.php?action=listentries&category=7 (second and third questions) you can't use the dmg (which you showed the link for) as a unix style installation directly. See the links on the above page for a DarwinPorts or Fink installation or, indeed, you'll have to build it from source as described on the page.

To directly answer your question, you should find the libraries in /Library/Frameworks/.