# Strange Error Messages When Installing Python Module with pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

When trying to install `pygame`on Mac, I got a lot of errors. I'm worried that it is due to me deleting a bunch of `python 2.7` files from various places. (See last question). I didn't realize until after I deleted them that it was a dumb thing to do. The only part that confuses me is that I successfully installed `numpy` a few days ago with no problems. If there is an alternate way for me to continue installing modules or to fix the issues, please help. Running Mac OSX --Sierra.

```
sudo pip3 install pygame

Password:
The directory '/Users/kendrick/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/kendrick/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-1.9.2.tar.gz (3.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.0MB 138kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using Darwin configuration...

/bin/sh: sdl-config: command not found
/bin/sh: sdl-config: command not found
/bin/sh: sdl-config: command not found
WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
Hunting dependencies...
SDL     : not found
Framework SDL not found
FONT    : not found
Framework SDL_ttf not found
IMAGE   : not found
Framework SDL_image not found
MIXER   : not found
Framework SDL_mixer not found
Framework CoreMIDI found
Framework QuickTime found
PNG     : not found
JPEG    : not found
PORTMIDI: not found
FREETYPE: found 2.6.1

If you get compiler errors during install, doublecheck
the compiler flags in the "Setup" file.


Continuing With "setup.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-03bu0lxv/pygame/setup.py", line 294, in <module>
    write_version_module(METADATA['version'], revision)
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-03bu0lxv/pygame/setup.py", line 286, in write_version_module
    with open('version.py.in', 'r') as header_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'version.py.in'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-03bu0lxv/pygame/
```

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122519/where-is-sdl-config-installed-on-macos-10-6-snow-leopard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a problem with version 1.9.2 of PyGame.
A few files were not included in the package, so that version is effectively useless.

Here is a link to the bug report:
https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/319/missing-versionpyin-in-source-tarball

And for completeness, the suggested solution is:

> Rats, I didn't check the sdist before it was uploaded. In the meantime, you can download a source tarball from Bitbucket:
>   https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/get/1.9.2.tar.gz